# Why is my ActionLink not generating properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I can not figure out why ActionLink is not generating the url correctly in this one instance.

I have a controller called Activity and a view called Show.  From there I'm trying to create a link to the ServiceCall controller, Show view.  From within any view on the ServiceCall this works fine:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(sc.CallNumber), "Show", new { callNumber = "100" })%>
```

From the Activity view, this is not working:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(sc.CallNumber), "Show", "ServiceCall", new { callNumber = "100" })%>
```

It is generating a link like http://localhost/Activity/Show/12?Length=11

After some research I decided to try this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(sc.CallNumber), "Show", new { controller = "ServiceCall" }, new { callNumber = "100" })%>
```

That gives me a url of http://localhost/ServiceCall/Show but does not give the callNumber.  Any ideas?

This is in my routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ShowCall",
            "ServiceCall/Show/{callNumber}",
            new {controller = "ServiceCall", action = "Show", callNumber = ""}
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(sc.CallNumber), "Show", "ServiceCall", new { callNumber = "100" }, null)%>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you are not calling the correct override. You need:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    sc.CallNumber,
    "Show",
    "ServiceCall",
    new { callNumber = "100" },
    null) %>
```

Notice the extra `null`. I had recently similar problem.

Edit: Also, I'm sure you don't need the `Html.Encode`. It's already being encoded.